# Handling comments stored parent document using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB for a CMS. I want to store the user-submitted comments in the parent document - approach no. 2 in [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/) official use case example.

As it is noted in the example, MongoDB has a 16MB limit per document. How can I continue adding comments in another document that would still refer to the original if I run out of space?

Comment: Have you looked at Grid FS? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've considered this problem recently.

One possibility would be to limit the size of comments on the front end and then only store a certain number of comments in the parent document as well as storing an `_id` of the next document full of comments and then use pagination widgets to continue making fetches for that next document of comments. This allows you to show the first few comments and then load the rest with a "Load More Comments" type button. I don't love the solution though.

Another solution would be to store all comments in a separate collection with a foreign key to the parent document's `_id`. Then you can search this collection when a user clicks "Show comments" and you can grab all of the comments for that document in one query. This is similar to a relational model so I also don't love it as a solution.